# How to add several files to a fileset at once with a regular expression?

Tags: customize, filesets

I'm working on the current branch of a game composed of several files. I have created a fileset so I can open all those files at once.  The GNU Emacs manual says:

> Normally, a fileset is a simple list of files, but you can also define
>   a fileset as a regular expression matching file names.

However, no way to enter a regular expression to add files to a fileset is provided in the manual (filesets-add-buffer only allows you to add the file you are currently visiting).

Comment: The manual says explicitly: "*edit the list of filesets directly, with **`M-x
filesets-edit`** (or by choosing `Edit Filesets` from the `Filesets`
menu).  The editing is performed in a Customize buffer (*note Easy
Customization::).  Normally, a fileset is a simple list of files, but
you can also define a fileset **as a regular expression matching file
names**.*" In the Customize buffer for option `filesets-data`, click the **`Value Menu`** for a given entry and choose **`Pattern`**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After calling the function `filesets-init`, either interactively via `M-: (filesets-init) RET` or in your `user-init-file` as `(filesets-init)`, you can invoke the command `M-x filesets-edit RET` to edit the user option `filesets-data` using the Customize interface.

This is the only interactive means of customising filesets I can see in the source. Alternatively, you could manually set/edit `filesets-data` in your `user-init-file`.

As per [Drew's suggestion](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/32981/how-to-add-several-files-to-a-fileset-at-once-with-a-regular-expression#comment50911_32982), here is the docstring for `filesets-data`, the main customisation entry-point for filesets:

```
Fileset definitions.

A fileset is either a list of files, a file pattern, a base directory
and a search pattern (for files), or a base file.  Changes to this
variable will take effect after rebuilding the menu.

Caveat: Fileset names have to be unique.

Example definition:
 '(("My Wiki"
    (:ingroup "~/Etc/My-Wiki/WikiContents"))
   ("My Homepage"
    (:pattern "~/public_html/" "^.+\\\\.html$")
    (:open filesets-find-file))
   ("User Configuration"
    (:files "~/.xinitrc"
            "~/.bashrc"
            "~/.bash_profile"))
   ("HOME"
    (:tree "~" "^[^.].*[^~]$")
    (:filter-dirs-flag t)))

`filesets-data' is a list of (NAME-AS-STRING . DEFINITION), DEFINITION
being an association list with the fields:

:files FILE-1 .. FILE-N ... a list of files belonging to a fileset

:ingroup FILE-NAME ... an inclusion group's base file.

:tree ROOT-DIR PATTERN ... a base directory and a file pattern

:pattern DIR PATTERN ... a base directory and a regexp matching
                         files in that directory.  Usually,
                         PATTERN has the form `^REGEXP$'.  Unlike
                         :tree, this form does not descend
                         recursively into subdirectories.

:filter-dirs-flag BOOLEAN ... is only used in conjunction with :tree.

:tree-max-level INTEGER ... recurse into directories this many levels
(see `filesets-tree-max-level' for a full explanation)

:dormant-flag BOOLEAN ... non-nil means don't show this item in the
menu; dormant filesets can still be manipulated via commands available
from the minibuffer -- e.g. `filesets-open', `filesets-close', or
`filesets-run-cmd'

:dormant-p FUNCTION ... a function returning :dormant-flag

:open FUNCTION ... the function used to open file belonging to this
fileset.  The function takes a file name as argument

:save FUNCTION ... the function used to save file belonging to this
fileset; it takes no arguments, but works on the current buffer.

Either :files, :pattern, :tree, or :ingroup must be supplied.  :files
overrules :tree, :tree overrules :pattern, :pattern overrules :ingroup,
i.e. these tags are mutually exclusive.  The fields :open and :save are
optional.

In conjunction with the :tree tag, :save is void.  :open refers to the
function used for opening files in a directory, not for opening the
directory.  For browsing directories, `filesets-browse-dir-function' is used.

Before using :ingroup, make sure that the file type is already
defined in `filesets-ingroup-patterns'.
```

Comment: +1. In sum, *customize option `filesets-data`*. And start by reading its doc string: `C-h v filesets-data`. (You might want to post that doc here.)